# Hazelcast: distributed execution and local member info

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm looking for the way to lookup local hazelcast member in the task execution. Version I'm working with is 2.5-SNAPSHOT. Snippet from the tutorial doesn't seem to be working:

```
public class Echo implements Callable<String>, Serializable {
    public String call() {
        return Hazelcast.getCluster().getLocalMember().toString() + ":" + input;
    }
}
```

Calling getCluster() that is deprecated now triggers **new member** to be created and connected.

At the moment I managed to get it via HazelcastInstance.getCluster().getLocalMember() but I 
would not like to complicate my callables with this kind of injection.

Could you please suggest the proper way to lookup local member?

Comment: proper way is not to lookup local members. do you have a reason why you'd need to do that?

Comment: Reasonable question. In general I should not do this. The idea is to execute task on lite members only. Not sure key ownership business will work here. I was confused with new member created on deprecated method call so I supposed the proper way do exist but it's different. Anyway I can schedule tasks using set of members I got via Cluster object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callable should implement HazelcastInstanceAware.

Here example:

```
public class EchoExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Config config = new Config();
        HazelcastInstance instance1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
        HazelcastInstance instance2 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
        ExecutorService executorService = instance1.getExecutorService("exec1");
        Future<String> future = executorService.submit(new Echo());
        System.out.println(future.get());

    }

    static class Echo implements HazelcastInstanceAware, Serializable, Callable<String> {
        transient HazelcastInstance localInstance;

        public String call() throws Exception {
            return localInstance.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
            this.localInstance = hazelcastInstance;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Splendid! Works as expected. Thank you! I'm just surprised how did I miss this in documentation? Probably because of lack of attention or maybe because there's only one single sentence about  it with no header and at the and of the chapter? :) http://hazelcast.com/docs/2.5/manual/single_html/#ExecutorService